# Office 365 tenant to tenant email migration, enable mail users on new tenant for migration

Tags: azure, powershell, email, office365

I'm working off of Microsoft tenant to tenant migration preview as found here to move all our user email to a different tenant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/cross-tenant-mailbox-migration?view=o365-worldwide

And I'm up to the step where I need to enable mail-users on the new tenant but nothing I have done so far has worked. I've been trying to use `New-MailUsers` to create a new external email address linked to the new user accounts but get an error that the proxy address is already in place so I have tried using the `Set-User <identity> -PermanentlyClearPreviousMailboxInfo` but that just says that it completed but nothing was changed.

I do have the new users created on the new tenant, and a couple of them are already licensed for mailboxes but the above does not work for either licensed nor unlicensed users.

Do I need to delete the user accounts completely and then try using the `New-MailUsers` to setup the external email address link for the new account? Or is there some step I'm missing somewhere?

[Trying to make new mail enabled user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEUeL.png)

[Trying to remove mailbox settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVeVJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell error says that there is already a mailbox with that SMTP.
When you assign licenses, new mailboxes get provisioned. You need to remove everything, set up mail users with an `exchangeGUID` first, and then assign licenses.

From [the article you referenced](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/cross-tenant-mailbox-migration?view=o365-worldwide#prerequisites-for-target-user-objects):

> 4. Users in the target organization must be licensed with appropriate Exchange Online subscriptions applicable for the organization. You may apply a license in advance of a mailbox move but ONLY once the target MailUser is properly set up with ExchangeGUID and proxy addresses. Applying a license before the ExchangeGUID is applied will result in a new mailbox provisioned in target organization.

Comment: When a mailbox gets provisioned, it generates it's own ExchangeGUID

Comment: Thanks, I think I realized this after testing a little bit more. How I read it initially was that if I had already created the user and licensed it for a mailbox I could use that second command with the -Permanent delete switch to fix it.